# How do I call google maps from a button?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to implement an app where when the user clicks on a button, a map is shown. I made another app using only the map as main activity and it works fine. But if I use the same code as another activity, and try to call it from a button, the app stops and no error is shown. I'm not sure if the error is on the map code or on the intent.

Main Activity

```
package com.br.appmedico.View;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.br.appmedico.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btProx, btEsp;
    TextView tvAche;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tvAche = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAche);
        btProx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btProx);
        btProx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btEsp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEsp);
        btEsp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),EspActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }



}
```

Maps Activity

```
package com.br.appmedico.View;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.br.appmedico.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.br.appmedico">

    <!-- verificar conexao -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- permissão para internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- permissao necessaria para maps v2 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".View.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBOe32znnSixywmiN0GzOJw8HKhPwUxvrA" />

        <activity
            android:name=".View.NearbyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nearby" />
        <activity android:name=".View.EspActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".View.ListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".View.Consul1Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.graddle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.br.appmedico"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Habilitando MultiDex
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: MapActivity is not added to AndroidManifest file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add your Map activity to your manifest.

Comment: Thank you., that was the problem.

Comment: Only problem now is that it shows a blank map... There is the google logo and a blank screen.

Comment: Does the log show any errors? Did you compare your code to how you used your map when you had it as the main activity? If you're using the map in a different app, did you get a new maps api key?

Comment: I created a new API key and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do but I don't think you need a separate MapActivity Class to accomplish it. You can simply get a String zip code, either from a user's input or a preference that they choose and use that String to launch google maps within your button's onClick method like this:

```
     String location = "02466"; //Get this from user input or preference

     Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
             .appendQueryParameter("q",location)
             .build();

     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setData(geoLocation);

     if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
         startActivity(i);
     }else{
         Log.v("Main", "An Error Occured");
     }
```

Comment: I want to show many maps with locations, as in a real state app. But I'm not sure how to do it.